# RGB LED voltage drop issue

Tags: rgb

i have RGB LED strip 173 LED in parallel.
i am driving from 5V 10A SMPS.

for R, G, B color it works fine universally light entire strip.
but when i go for white color then half of the strip little warm or natural white color.
i check voltage across each LED it is 4.7V at starting of strip but after half strip it going to 3.2 to 2.5 voltage.

what will be the issue any suggetion..?

Comment: Perhaps the resistance over the length of strip is too high for the required current. Try connecting both sides of the strip in parallel to the same power supply.

Comment: You need to drive both ends of the LED strip with a strong 5V. If the string is looped back to the power supply this is easy – just hook supply to both ends. In the more likely event that the end of the strip is far from the power supply, the best you can do is run a parallel set of wires (5V and ground from supply) of reasonable gauge alongside the strip and attach to far end of strip. The impedance of the these wires are far less than the strip so the far end voltage will end up being much closer to 5V. I had to do this on a home project with 4 strips wired around a room in a loop.